# Regex in XSLT 1.0 using java

Tags: java, regex, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this simple test:

```
<xsl:if test="boolean(java:java.util.regex.Pattern.matches('a', 'a'))">
        <xsl:message terminate="no">success</xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

Though it throws this error:

```
ERROR:  'Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(string, string)''
FATAL ERROR:  'Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(string, string)''
```

I know that java utilities work, as the code below compiles fine:

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a'), java:java.util.Date.new())"/>
```

Am I using `Pattern.matches()` incorrectly or is there a trick I'm missing?
I can't seem to find any solid documentation on java inside xslt.

I have declared the java namespace at the top of my document:

```
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `Pattern.matches` is

```
static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input)
```

Note that the second argument is not `String` but `CharSequence` and that there is no mapping defined between `String`(XSLT) and `CharSequence` (Java). So you have to do the conversion manually by creating an object of a class implementing the required interface `CharSequence` (e.g. `java.lang.String`).

If you change your XSLT test expression to

```
java:java.util.regex.Pattern.matches('a', java:java.lang.String.new('a'))
```

it works.

This is described in the documentation for Xalan-Java, see https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ext-functions for more detailed information.

Nevertheless I found that it does not always seem to work as documented; manually creating an object of type `java.lang.String` sometimes just doesn't work. Then you have to try using other classes implementing the required interface, in this case anything that takes a Java string and provides the required Java character sequence interface, e.g. `java.lang.StringBuffer` or `java.lang.StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Markus. I appreciate that it wasn't just "here is a working solution". This has cleared a few blockers I've ran into when using java in xslt.

Comment: @XavierDass Thank you. I just realized I forgot to add the documentation link you also asked for. See updated answer for more.